# spring security always giving access denied page after successful login

Tags: spring, security

I am using spring security for my crud application. Even after successful login , spring redirects to access denied page.

This is my config file

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

  <security:form-login  default-target-url="/employees" 
                        authentication-failure-url="/" always-use-default-target="true" 
                        authentication-success-handler-ref="UrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
</security:http>

<beans:bean id="UrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
            class="com.sowmith.security.UrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" /> 

<security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="false">
  <security:authentication-provider>
    <security:user-service>
      <security:user name="sowmith" password="reddy" authorities="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    </security:user-service>
  </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String welcome(){
    return "welcome";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
//@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public String listEmployee(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
    model.addAttribute("listEmployee", employeeService.listEmployee());
    model.addAttribute("user", getPrincipal());
    return "employee";
}
```

AuthenticationsuccessHandler class

```
protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, 
                      Authentication authentication) throws IOException{

    String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);
    if(response.isCommitted()){
        log.debug("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + targetUrl);
        return;
    }
    redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
}


protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication){

    boolean permitAll = false;
    boolean isAdmin = false;
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
    for(GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities){
        if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("permitAll")) {
            permitAll = true;
        } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")) {
            isAdmin = true;
        }
    }
    if (permitAll){
        return "/";
    } else if (isAdmin) {
        return "/employees";
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
```

In determine target url method, it is checking for the role and redirecting to the target url. but it is not hitting the controller.

Comment: share your UrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify an admin in authentication manager tag of your spring security xml file like this

```
<security:user name="sowmith" password="reddy" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
```

Then change if condition that's checking role in your AuthenticationSuccessHandler class to

```
else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN"))
```

Comment: In xml based config, I doubt that hasRole expression is applicable in specifying a user's authorities just as it can be used to determine access right to a given url pattern. I stand to be corrected though. That's the reason I suggested you should exclude it in other not to complicate things.